# Excel Addin using React for Taskpane with custom functions

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am new to Office Addins and Office.js.

I am developing a Excel Addin surrounding Custom Functions. I would really like to use react for the taskpane but I can't seem to get both working simultaneously.

I was wondering if anyone has gotten a React Taskpane addin with custom functions working? What does you Manifest and webpack files look like and any other traps a beginner might be falling into preventing this from working.

Edit:

Expected outcome:
To be able to develop custom functions for excel such as CLOCK (Screenshot below) through a function.js file.
[image]

I would like to use react as the framework for developing the taskpane (on the right of the screenshot).

I have tried to achieve this a couple times, a mixture of merging yo office templates and following the documentation.

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>9bf11fda-0020-4224-b93b-28d93053f814</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="RTS"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
          <AllFormFactors>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
              <Script>
                <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
              </Script>
              <Page>
                <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
              </Page>
              <Metadata>
                <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
              </Metadata>
              <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/functions.js"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/functions.json"/>      
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="CONTOSO"/>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Here is the webpack file:

```
 /* eslint-disable no-undef */
const CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin = require("custom-functions-metadata-plugin");
const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
      functions: "./src/functions/functions.js"
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
        output: "functions.json",
        input: "./src/functions/functions.js", 
     }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills", "functions"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

I create a function such as this in src/functions/functions.js

```
/**
* Returns the provided message
 * @customfunction
 * @param {string} message Message
 * @returns {string} Returns the message.
 */
export function testMessage(message) {
    return message;
}
```

I can see it exports the function metadata when npm run build is done.
[image]

With this current setup, I can continue using react and editing the taskpane like a normal React Addin. However none of the functions appear in Excel at all.
[image]

Comment: Please provide more detail about what is going wrong. What steps lead up to the problem. What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Comment: @RickKirkham Let me know if there is more details required.

Comment: Is the functions.js (in addition to the functions.json) in the dist folder? It looks like functions.js is not mentioned in the "entry" property in the webpack.config.js file, which makes me suspect that it is not being outputted by webpack.

Comment: @RickKirkham I have added
      functions: "./src/functions/functions.js"
The dist folder does now have functions.js and functions.js.map
Still no functions in Excel though. Do I need to reference the functions file elsewhere as well possibly?

Comment: If you aren't using a Shared Runtime, which your manifest indicates you are not, then the custom functions run in a completely different runtime from the task pane. This means you need to get the functions.js and possibly the functions.json to be loaded in the custom functions runtime. But Microsoft recommends that you use a shared runtime when you have custom functions and a task pane.

Comment: See [Excel custom functions quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart) and [Configure your add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) and [Runtimes in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtimes).

Comment: @RickKirkham I believe I have now configured shared runtime with no success regarding the functions. I updated the original code snippets above.

Comment: Try having the handler that is assigned to the Run button in the task pane make a call of your `testMessage` function. See if it actually runs or you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it was probably a mix of things as per the the comments above.

The final fix that got it working was an error in my manifest file. My `<AllFormFactors>` tag was within the `<DesktopFormFactor>` tag.

Working Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>9bf11fda-0020-4224-b93b-28d93053f814</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="RTS"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long"/>
        </Runtimes>
        <AllFormFactors>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
              <Script>
                <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
              </Script>
              <Page>
                <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
              </Page>
              <Metadata>
                <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
              </Metadata>
              <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </AllFormFactors>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
          
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/functions.js"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/functions.json"/>      
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="CONTOSO"/>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```